# Why does an error in a separate JS file make my JS file code never execute?

Tags: javascript

**Short Question:**
Why does an error in a separate JS file stop my JS file's code from executing?

**Long Question with context:**
So I have a JavaScript (JS) file that is never executing its code because a 3rd party JS file throws an error. Now I thought because these are 2 separate files that that 3rd party file's errors wouldn't stop my JS file's code from executing, am I correct on that? Weirdly, I've created my own test where I first load a JS file that throws an error then I load my JS file and my JS file's code executes. So I'm really confused why this 3rd party JS file error would stop my code from executing. Can you provide any insight/advice?

Here's how the html is organised for context:

**home.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebpage.com/js/thirdparty.min.js?ver=4.6.5"></script>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebpage.com/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebpage.com/js/myscript.js?ver=5.5.1"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**thirdparty.min.js** is a minified, bundle of 3rd partly libraries related to sticky navs, and lots of other functionality. I'll provide the erroneous line of code below, because it's minified it's probably not useful except for context:

```
...
Vt = g()(window),
qt = K.b.jQuery(K.b),  // this is the error line - Uncaught TypeError: K.b.jQuery is not a function
$t = !d()(window, K.b),
Qt = $t ? ["app", "top"] : ["app"],
...
```

**myscript.js** is a long file but I've put its main entry point below for context:

```
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.initMyStuff();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

So my question is, why does an error in a separate JS file stop my code from executing?

---

My own test doesn't replicate the issue. Ie, if I replace `thirdparty.min.js` with my own file (`debug.js`) that has the same error `myscript.js`'s code still executes. What the heck is going on?

**debug.js**

```
!function(t) {
    "use strict";
    var K = {b: false}
    var qt = K.b.jQuery(K.b), foo = 'abc'; // the same error is thrown BUT my scripts code still executes
}();
```

Comment: 1) Your test likely doesn't replicate the environment that the error is occurring within. For example, `this` may be different. 2) When an exception happens, you'll usually get a stack trace. That stack trace should have at least one call from your code in addition to the call leading directly to the error.

Comment: Separate files will make no difference. All the JS code is executed in same thread. So ideally, unhandled error in any file should kill the execution, if its connected. You must be calling some function of this lib. Try to wrap it in `try...catch` to be sure

Comment: @sazr put the jquery script above the third party code: The order of scripts: 1: jQuery, 2: Third party code, 3: myscript.js